# Parsing Json Value in sql server

Tags: json, parsing

I am using sqlserver 2012.My table(bindings) contains following datas.

```
e_id     f_id      value

1001     1         [{"id":85574},{"id":169794},{"id":151336}]')
1002     1         [{"id":85574},{"id":169794}]') 

i want to select e_id and value(parsed value) from the above table.

Sample output.

e_id            value

1001            85574
1001            169794
1001            151336
1002            85574
1002            16974
```

i tried Using parsejson function(userdefined function) found in 
    https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/

```
select StringValue from parsejson('[{"id":85574},{"id":169794},{"id":151336}]')->This query Returns result.

select e_id,(Select stringvalue from parseJSON(v1.value)) from bindings v1 where  v1.value<>'' and v1.f_id=1 

showing error message Subquery returned more than 1 value"

 Below query also.

select (select stringvalue from parseJSON(v1.value)) from bindings v1 where f_id=1
```

Not able to parse values from table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to parse this json on server side in c# first and then insert only values part in the DB.